# Why is illumi after alluka?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Why is Illumi after Alluka's power?
 Does it have something much more powerful than just creation n destruction.

Answer (score 2):

Alluka's power can grant any wish.
In return, Alluka will request (After granting said wish) 3 requests, with their difficulties adjusted to how complicated/strong the wish is. (Not sure how to word this)

If three requests are granted, you may wish again. If three requests are denied, people die. The number of people increases as I've said before. The people who die, die by order of closeness to the target. (Minimum 2 people)

Thus, if they were to harness Alluka's power, it would be mindboggingly useful, and would make the Zoldick family as strong as they can only imagine.
But if someone were to abuse it and fail the requests, the results would be devastating for them. (And Illuka believed that Killua wanted to bear the requests of his wish)

Illumi also believed there are rules they are unaware of, and only Killua knows of, and again, he is correct, and this would make anticipating and controlling Alluka much harder. Thus, he intended to destroy her.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **ONE** of the reason why illumi is after alluka is because... So after Gon's fight with Neferpitou gon reached the limit of his nen, sinced he reached an incredible limit of his nen gon he started to die but slowly, Killus brother/sister has the power to make any request come true so killua requested that gon stop dying (something like that) but illumi wanted to kill alluka so that gon wouldnt be able to get better because the whole zoldyck family except for alluka wanted killua to become an assasin and leave gon behind. so that is basically why Illumi is after alluka

Answer (score 0):

I mean to be honest, we can only speculate why he wants her. The most obvious reason is to probably use her powers. Alluka has a pretty deadly and powerful ability so a good reason for him to go after Alluka is just to use her powers. Another reason is just to kill her, they dont really need her for anything and I doubt a Zoldyck would have a problem killing a sibling if they find them worthless. She's kind of in the way of a lot of things. So every Zoldyck wants Killua to become an assassin how're you supposed to influence him if you cant even get near him without getting teleported half way across the continent, I'll tell you how, you cant it's impossible so killing Alluka would be the easiest option. Who knows honestly he's a weird fellow but by the pace that Hunter x Hunter is going we're probably not going to know the answer for another 20 years